# Flutter Invalid argument(s): Missing Library (build_runner failure)

Tags: flutter, build-runner

I'm using Flutter [auto_route_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route_generator) package (which is based on [built_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner)) to generate [auto_routes](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route).

When I run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` I'm getting the above exception:

> [SEVERE] auto_route_generator:autoRouteGenerator on
> lib/main_staging.dart (cached):
>
> Invalid argument(s): Missing library: package:tenant_app/app/app.dart

**I encountered this issue after upgrading the Flutter version** from `3.0.5` to `3.3.1`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.1, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64, locale en-IL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.70.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

I tried to run the build_runner using `--delete-conflicting-outputs` but it didn't help

> flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

What is the problem? Why the build_runner is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue solved

Running the following tasks solved my issue:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub cache repair`
3. `flutter pub get`
4. `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

It seems that there was an issue with the cached packages after upgrading the Flutter version. Still, don't know what exactly happened.